# Possibility of Migration from Sisense to Microsoft Power BI

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, sisense

We are using Sisense for our reporting tool.
We have too many clients using Sisense.
This clients have a lot many dashboard , widget.

Sisense store data in mongo db.
I don't have an idea about Microsoft power BI.

Is there any possibility to build migrate tool for Sisense to Microsoft Power BI ?

Thank you.

Comment: No, you have to recreate everything in Power BI, they are two separate tools, with to methods of getting and storing data

Comment: @Jon, Thanks for the response.  Accepted both are separate tool but something should be done. Sisense storing data in mongodb. do you know where power bi store the data ?

Answer (score 2):

For Sisense, it stores its meta-data for it in a mongo db instance. However for Power BI it stores it's meta data in the PBIX file. If you change the file extension from pbix to zip, you can navigate in inspect the contents.

When the report is deployed to the Power BI Service, it uses a number of components to store the file and meta data, blob storage and a small SQL instance in the background. You cannot access these items or the data in them.

For on premise versions of Power BI, Power BI Report Server (available in Premium only, or some enterprise licensing), this requires a SQL Server database to be used. This acts as a meta data store for the Power BI Front end and, also stores the files etc for the reports loaded to it. You can access this data meta store. More details on the setup [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/install-report-server).

I don't think there is a path to migrate data from the mongo db to the sql, or the service, or the files, it will be a full recreate of the objects from one reporting technology to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, PowerBI uses XML and SiSense uses JAQL; parse the JAQL to create a translator to build rudimentary PowerBI reports. Since SiSense uses Elasticubes, Dashboards and Widgets, you have to parse them all to build out PowerBI. I successfully did this for SSRS and powerBI has a more complex layout but nonetheless, can be done...
Built it in .Net using Newtonsoft to extracts the JAQL (JSON) and then parse to translate to PowerBI..
not that hard

Comment: Thanks @Rick for your response. Did you accomplish from Sisense to Power BI ? I know the Sisense but new for the power BI.